# In Azure DevOps, how can I query the work items' log?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, how can I query which work items had entered a certain state ("Pending testing" for example) in a given time frame?

The obvious challenge is to show work items that have been changed into that state during that time period, but their state changed later on out of that state into another.

Answer (score 0):

It depends... The built-in states have a rule associated to them that will automatically set the current date/time to the `[State]Date` field. So there is a "AcceptedDate" and a "ClosedDate" for example.

For a Azure DevOps Inherited process, you can configure your own process to do the same. First you need to create the field to store the date in:

[image]

(optionally) Hide the field from the Work item Form:

[image]

Then add a rule that sets the value of the associated `[State]Date` field, if the value hasn't been set before:

[image]

Then it's easy to query any work item that entered this state before or after the specified date.

For Azure DevOps XML templates, you can do the same thing, but it requires a bit more configuration. There is a rule defined in the XML of teh work item type:

```
...
      <FIELD name="Closed Date" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension">
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>

...

        <TRANSITION from="New" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
...
```

And again, you can add your own rules in the same way. Then use `witadmin` to upload the workitem to your Team project

```
witadmin importwitd /f productbacklogitem.xml /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

You can find witadmin in the Team Explorer extension of Visual Studio:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022>dir /s /b witadmin.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\witadmin.exe
```

If you didn't do this yet and want [to historically query the data, you can use the `ASOF` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#specify-historical-queries-asof). You can't define such a query with the built-in query editor or Visual Studio, but there are extensions that allow you to do this:

- [Historic Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FlorianEckert.historic-query)
- [WIQL Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor)

A final option is to query the data through the ODATA feed or using the REST API.